# Is it possible for a macro to expand to code that will be executed exactly once when a program starts, regardless of how many times it's used?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, c-preprocessor

In my Qt apps, I use a preprocessor macro to automatically both declare and register a meta-type:

```
#define Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    static struct TYPE ## _metatype_registrar { \
        TYPE ## _metatype_registrar() { \
            qRegisterMetaType<TYPE>(); \
        } \
    } _ ## TYPE ## _metatype_registrar;
```

I generally use it in a header file after defining a type that I want to be usable with Qt's meta-type system, such as:

```
struct MyDataType {
    int foo;
    double bar;
};

Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(MyDataType)
```

It works because the static struct instance it defines will always have its constructor called when a program starts. I prefer this approach because now I don't need to separately register each type I care about somewhere in my code at the start of the program. (I used to use that approach and I frequently forgot to add new types there because I'm forgetful, resulting in annoying runtime errors.)

The one problem with using this macro though is that a type will be registered once for every source file that includes its corresponding use of `Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE`.

Technically Qt allows calling `qRegisterMetaType` multiple times for the same type, and ignores the subsequent calls. So this doesn't result in any errors. But this still strikes me as inefficient and unclean. Every source file that includes a header -- directly or indirectly -- which uses `Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE` will expand it to code defining a separate static struct whose constructor will execute at startup, littering the compiled code with tons of redundant structs and functions, all of which will be executed.

I'd like to see if I can improve it so that each use of `Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE` for a particular type results in it only executing the code it expands to once per type throughout the entire program, and (as something of a "stretch" goal) doesn't create redundant structs, assuming that's possible.

Put more specifically, if the header file `foo.h` contains the line `Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(Foo)`, and the files `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, and `c.cpp` all include `foo.h`, I want the compiled program only call `qRegisterMetaType<Foo>();` exactly once. And if possible, I want it to not create multiple redundant instances of `_Foo_metatype_registrar`.

If not for the efficiency and cleanliness reasons, I'd like to do so I can maybe learn some interesting C++ precompiler tricks!

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Look what Qt made you do. That's not pretty.

Comment: You could perhaps utilize [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of problem that can be resolved with a singleton pattern. In a nutshell, the singleton pattern ensures only a single instance of a type is ever created.

One approach could be to create an inner singleton class that implements your registration action in the constructor. Then, your outer class would obtain the singleton instance within its constructor. No matter how many `static` outer classes are created, the inner class is a singleton, so its constructor will only be called once. Putting all that together, your macro could be rewritten like this:

```
#define Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    static struct TYPE ## _metatype_registrar { \
        class inner { \
            inner() { qRegisterMetaType<TYPE>(); } \
            inner(const inner &) = delete; \
            void operator=(const inner &) = delete; \
        public: \
            static inner & once () { \
                static inner instance; \
                return instance; \
            } \
        }; \
        TYPE ## _metatype_registrar() { \
            inner::once(); \
        } \
    } _ ## TYPE ## _metatype_registrar;
```

I did investigate `std::call_once`, and it does work.

```
#define Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    static struct TYPE ## _metatype_registrar { \
        TYPE ## _metatype_registrar() { \
            static std::once_flag f; \
            std::call_once(f, qRegisterMetaType<TYPE>); \
        } \
    } _ ## TYPE ## _metatype_registrar;
```

However, this requires that you `#include <mutex>` and link with your threading library, which may seem strange if your program is not multi-threaded.

Note, these will prevent multiple registrations from occurring. However, your solution method requires ***static*** instances to be defined in the translation units by the header files, because otherwise you would violate the one definition rule. Thus, the solutions above do not resolve the issue of your code being littered with these redundant static objects.

---

However, there is a way around this if you use templates. C++ has a special case for template classes, where by it will automatically consolidate redundant static member definitions into a single definition. This is because templates are implemented entirely in header files, where its static members are also typically defined. So, you could create a generic template class for your registrar.

```
template <typename T>
class MetatypeRegistrar {
    MetatypeRegistrar () { qRegisterMetatype<T>(); }
public:
    static MetatypeRegistrar _registrar;
};

template <typename T>
MetatypeRegistrar<T> MetatypeRegistrar<T>::_registrar;
```

Notice how the last two lines provides the template definition for the static member declaration of `_registrar`.

And now, you can effect the automatic registration in your header file for your type with this macro:

```
#define Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_METATYPE(TYPE) \
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE) \
template class MetatypeRegistrar<TYPE>;
```

This is essentially an explicit instantiation of the template with the provided type.

Multiple source files may create multiple instantiations of the template for the same `MyDataType` as the header file is included. However, the compiler will consolidate the implied multiple instances of the static template class data member into a single instance automatically.

Comment: That's quite clever! I hadn't considered using an inner singleton class. There is one other possible solution I found, which is to modify the original macro to include a static bool that gets set to true when `qRegisterMetaType` is called, and then prevents calling it if it's already true. Something like `static bool needInit = true; if (needInit) { qRegisterMetaType<TYPE>(); needInit = false; }`. This seems to have the same advantages and disadvantages: it requires a single static variable, `qRegisterMetaType` is called once, and it still litters the app with redundant structs.

Comment: I'm starting to think that getting rid of the redundant structs are a more important goal of this question than I thought, because looking at the assembler created for my project reveals tons of unnecessary global variables all of which are being initialized at startup. That said, I'm starting to doubt that there's any way to prevent that from happening short of using some kind of custom preprocessor step before compilation. (Given I'm already using one with Qt, it's too bad they don't offer automatic type registration as a feature!)

Comment: @GuyGizmo: The static flag can be used, but is error prone if you ever go multi-threaded. So, you would need some way to flag the issue to be fixed if that were the case. The C++ singleton idiom will be thread safe per language specification.

Comment: @GuyGizmo: But, yes, my last paragraph was meant to warn you that your desire to perform the registration in the header file makes it necessary to create these redundant objects. You might consider conditional compilation flags to selectively enable/disable the registration code generation. By default, no registration code is generated. Then, in a special source file, you include all the header files that need the registration code, and change the flags so that the registration code gets generated.

Comment: @jhx Yes, I've considered that, but that's essentially the same as my original approach, which was just to have a function somewhere in my code that explicitly calls `qRegisterMetaType` for every type that needs it. If I'm going to do something that's not automatic, I may as well keep it simple and do that. The reason I'm trying to avoid that is because I'm a forgetful clod and would constantly forget to add types to that function, resulting in runtime errors that were sometimes hard to track down. So I'm looking for a clever automatic method that doesn't create too much garbage.

Comment: @GuyGizmo: Updated my answer. See the addition at the bottom using explicit template instantiation.

Comment: Brilliant, you got it! I had a feeling templates would work their way into the solution somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to jhx's answer:

This method can fail for types that are `QObject`-derived classes and have been forward declared as an opaque pointer type using `Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER`, e.g.:

```
class MyClass;
Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER(MyClass *)
```

The trouble is that there's no control over where exactly the instance of `MetatypeRegistrar` will be instantiated for a particular type, and if it happens to occur in a source file that, somewhere in its chain of headers, includes `Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER` for the type being registered, then the meta-type system will not see it as a `QObject`-derived class and attempts to get the class's meta-object using the meta-type system will fail and return a null pointer.

The solution is to ensure thast the `MetatypeRegistrar` instance is only instantiated if the class has not been declared as an opaque pointer:

```
template <typename T>
class MetatypeRegistrar {
    MetatypeRegistrar () {
        qRegisterMetaType<T *>();
    }
public:
    static MetatypeRegistrar _registrar;
};

template <typename T>
MetatypeRegistrar<T> MetatypeRegistrar<T>::_registrar;

template<class T>
using EnsureFullyDefined =
    typename std::conditional<QtPrivate::IsPointerToTypeDerivedFromQObject<T *>::Value, T, void>::type;

#define Q_REGISTER_QOBJECT_METATYPE(TYPE) \
template class MetatypeRegistrar<EnsureFullyDefined<TYPE>>;

#define Q_DECLARE_AND_REGISTER_QOBJECT_METATYPE(TYPE) \
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE*) \
    Q_REGISTER_QOBJECT_METATYPE(TYPE)
```

This makes use of some private Qt internals: `QtPrivate::IsPointerToTypeDerivedFromQObject`. So this method may fail in a later version of Qt. But currently it works in both Qt 5 and 6. `IsPointerToTypeDerivedFromQObject` defines a compile-time constant that is true for types that are derived from `QObject`, and false for non-`QObject` types or any type that has been declared opaque using `Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER`. So we can use this to determine if it's safe to register a particular `QObject`-derived type.

This means that there could be at most two instances of `MetatypeRegistrar` instantiated for any particular `QObject`-derived type rather than one, but that's a small price to pay to ensure that this method continues to consistently work.